# Merge two JTokens into one

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can I merge these two JTokens into one single JToken. This sounds like it should be simple, but can't get my way around it.

```
{
  "data":[
  {
      "ID":"53a1862000404a304942546b35519ba3",
      "name":"Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL",
      "objCode":"ARVPTH"
  }]
}

{
"data":[
  {
      "ID":"53a1838200401324eb1ec66562e9d77d",
      "name":"Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL",
      "objCode":"ARVPTH"
  }]
}
```

Thanks for the help!

This is what I have tried so far:

I started by assigning the first object to a variable `Jtoken pageOne` then, I tried concatenating it into a second variable `JToken allPages`. I have a loop that brings back multiple pages each with three fields. The final goal is to grab each page and create a big J`Token` with all of the pages in it.

something like this:

```
for (int page = 0; page <= recCount; page += 2000)
{
 //Get data
 pageOne = getJsonData();
 allPages.Concat(pageOne);
}
return allPages;
```

Comment: What about creating JToken[] array?

Comment: what effort did you put in to achieve it, provide sample on what you have done so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`JContainer.Merge(Object, JsonMergeSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Merge_1.htm) to merge one `JObject` onto another.  Note that [`JsonMergeSettings.MergeArrayHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonMergeSettings_MergeArrayHandling.htm) gives control over how arrays are merged.  From the [`MergeArrayHandling` Enumeration documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_MergeArrayHandling.htm), the possible merge options are:

> ```
> Concat   0   Concatenate arrays.
> Union    1   Union arrays, skipping items that already exist.
> Replace  2   Replace all array items.
> Merge    3   Merge array items together, matched by index.
> ```

Thus merging using `MergeArrayHandling.Concat` as follows, where `allPages` and `pageOne` are both of type `JContainer` (or a subclass, such as `JObject`):

```
JContainer allPages = null;
var settings = new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat };
for (int page = 0; page <= recCount; page += 2000)
{
    //Get data
    var pageOne = (JContainer)getJsonData(page);
    if (allPages == null)
        allPages = pageOne;
    else
        allPages.Merge(pageOne, settings);
}
return allPages;
```

gives:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "53a1862000404a304942546b35519ba3",
      "name": "Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL",
      "objCode": "ARVPTH"
    },
    {
      "ID": "53a1838200401324eb1ec66562e9d77d",
      "name": "Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL",
      "objCode": "ARVPTH"
    }
  ]
}
```

While merging using `Replace` gives:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "53a1838200401324eb1ec66562e9d77d",
      "name": "Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL",
      "objCode": "ARVPTH"
    }
  ]
}
```

If your variables are of type `JToken` you will need to cast them to `JContainer`.  (JSON primitives that are not containers cannot be merged.)

[`JsonMergeSettings.MergeNullValueHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonMergeSettings_MergeNullValueHandling.htm) gives control over whether to merge or ignore `null` values, as required.

Comment: Sounds great! what I really need is the Concat. How would you write that?
Would it be something like this:
`object1.Concat(object2);`

Comment: @JoseStack - added an example call.

Comment: For some reason

`JContainer allPages;`


`allPages.****`

 wont give me the Merge option... am I missing something?

Comment: @JoseStack - note that merge was added to Json.NET in [Json.NET 6.0 Release 4](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/08/04/json-net-6-0-release-4-json-merge-dependency-injection)

Comment: It works as expected! my version was outdated as well. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could merge it like that (or if you had it had it in an array or list you could make a linq group by query for example over the ID property, that would be likewise effective).

```
  var data1 =  JObject.Parse(@"{
           'data':[
          {
             'ID':'53a1862000404a304942546b35519ba3',
              'name':'Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL',
              'objCode':'ARVPTH'
          }]
        }");

        var data2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
           'data':[
          {
             'ID':'53a1862000404a304942546b35519ba3',
              'name':'Private Approval Process: Draft Document CPL',
              'objCode':'ARVPTH'
          }]
        }");

        data1.Merge(data2, new JsonMergeSettings
        {
           MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
        });

        string json = data1.ToString();
```