# Populate existing JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

In short, I need a `JToken.Parse(string)` that don't create new instance of `JToken`, but instead modifies already existing one.

My specific task requires that I don't use `Jtoken.Parse(string)`, which is creating new instance of `JToken`, but instead forces me to use already existing instance of `JToken` that I have to populate with some data.
Initially `JToken existingInstance` is an empty `JToken` and I have a json `string` that has data I need to put into `existingInstance`.
Sorry, but I can't find any approaches here.
I tried to recursively copy one from another, but `Add` only supported in `JObject`
There are many questions about populating already existing object of some type, but I can't find anything about populating already existing `JToken`.

Example JSON file I use:

```
{
  "type": "stated",
  "width": 32,
  "height": 32,
  "speed": 0.1,
  "states": [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "count": 4,
    },{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 32,
      "count": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You could load the string to a new `JContainer` then merge it onto the existing `JContainer`.  See [Merge two JTokens into one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37756656/3744182).  Note this only works for containers (`JObject` and `JArray`).  The primitive `JValue` cannot be merged.

Comment: @dbc, Thanks! Looking good! I'll post it as an answer, if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.